# erb <% expression -%> in aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ruby, erb, viewengine

Do asp.net aspx views have tags that that work similar to the Ruby erb `<% -%>` ?
I don't like all these line breaks in my asp.net mvc generated html.
As for the other view engines (nhaml, spark, razor) I don't want to use them yet.

Quick example of the difference between <% %> and <% -%> in erb:

**1. <% %>**

```
<% 3.times do %>
Ho!<br />
<% end %>
Merry Christmas!
```

gives us:

```
Ho!<br />

Ho!<br />

Ho!<br />

Merry Christmas!
```

**2. <% -%>**

```
<% 3.times do -%>
Ho!<br />
<% end -%>
Merry Christmas!
```

gives us:

```
  Ho!<br />
  Ho!<br />
  Ho!<br />
  Merry Christmas!
```

Comment: You might want to explain what that tag does that you need, for people that don't know Ruby but might know how to achieve that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<% %>` Exists
`<% -%>` Does not exists

There is small chance that Razor has it. I haven't checked it yet.

---

To other answerers:

Notice that small minus sign. In rails it means that blank lines will be stripped out.

Comment: That's a pity, I was hoping there is a way to deal with long, full of blank lines HTML in asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you say mimic, as this notation on classic asp and asp.net predates ruby erb.

However, it does exist, and is almost identical. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0111sbh.aspx) (code blocks), [expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx) and [binding expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not misstaken you shoud be able to use <%= expression %> in asp.net to output values